# FFMPEG width not divisible by 2 (639x360)

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using python wrapper command of ffmepeg. I followed the tutorial from here for a "Production ready HLS" : https://docs.peer5.com/guides/production-ready-hls-vod/

This is my code:

```
 subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-y', '-i', download_path,
                     '-vf', 'scale=w=640:h=360:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease', \
                     '-c:a', 'aac', '-ar', '48000', '-c:v', 'h264', \
                     '-profile:v', 'main', '-crf', '20', '-sc_threshold', '0', \
                     '-g', '48', '-keyint_min', '48', '-hls_time', '4', \
                     '-hls_playlist_type', 'vod',  '-b:v', '800k', \
                     '-maxrate', '856k', '-bufsize', '1200k', '-b:a', '96k', \
                     '-hls_segment_filename', upload_path + \
                     '/360p_%03d.ts', upload_path + '/360p.m3u8', \
                     '-vf', 'scale=w=842:h=480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease', \
                     '-c:a', 'aac', '-ar', '48000', '-c:v', 'h264', \
                     '-profile:v', 'main', '-crf', '20', '-sc_threshold', '0', \
                     '-g', '48', '-keyint_min', '48', '-hls_time', '4', \
                     '-hls_playlist_type', 'vod', '-b:v', '1400k', \
                     '-maxrate', '1498k', '-bufsize', '2100k', '-b:a', '128k', \
                     '-hls_segment_filename', upload_path + \
                     '/480p_%03d.ts', upload_path + '/480p.m3u8', \
                     '-vf', 'scale=w=1280:h=720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease', \
                     '-c:a', 'aac', '-ar', '48000', '-c:v', 'h264', \
                     '-profile:v', 'main', '-crf', '20', '-sc_threshold', '0', \
                     '-g', '48', '-keyint_min', '48', '-hls_time', '4', \
                     '-hls_playlist_type', 'vod', '-b:v', '2800k', \
                     '-maxrate', '2996k', '-bufsize', '4200k', '-b:a', '128k', \
                     '-hls_segment_filename', upload_path + \
                     '/720p_%03d.ts', upload_path + '/720p.m3u8', \
                     '-vf', 'scale=w=1920:h=1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease', \
                     '-c:a', 'aac', '-ar', '48000', '-c:v', 'h264', \
                     '-profile:v', 'main', '-crf', '20', '-sc_threshold', '0', \
                     '-g', '48', '-keyint_min', '48', '-hls_time', '4', \
                     '-hls_playlist_type', 'vod', '-b:v', '5000k', \
                     '-maxrate', '5350k', '-bufsize', '7500k', '-b:a', '192k', \
                     '-hls_segment_filename', upload_path + '/1080p_%03d.ts', upload_path + '/1080p.m3u8'])
```

And getting this output

```
[libx264 @ 0x7fb95500c800] width not divisible by 2 (639x360)
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Any ideas of whats going wrong?

Comment: It's probably `force_original_aspect_ratio` forcing the output dimensions to be slightly wrong - try dropping that?

Comment: problem solved; thanks!

Comment: Don't drop it. Add `force_divisible_by=2`